# Linux uio_pdrv_genirq module does not create device

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I would like to expose some IRQ to user-space using `uio_pdrv_genirq` driver on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. However, I've faced some problems that the device `/dev/uio0` is not created (on first module load).

I use raspbian with kernel 5.2.2-v7l+, but I've started with kernel 4.19.57-v7l+ with the same results.

I've prepared device-tree overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
        fragment@0 {
                target = <&gpio>;
                __overlay__ {
                        mfrc522_uio_pins: mfrc522_uio_pins {
                                brcm,pins = <4>;
                                brcm,function = <0>; //<BCM2835_FSEL_GPIO_IN>;
                                brcm,pull = <0>; //<BCM2835_PUD_OFF>;
                        };
                };
        };

        fragment@1 {
                target-path = "/";
                __overlay__ {
                        mfrc522_uio: mfrc522_uio {
                                compatible = "mfrc522-uio,generic-uio";
                                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                                interrupts = <4 1>; // IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING
                                pinctrl-names = "default";
                                pinctrl-0 = <&mfrc522_uio_pins>;
                                status = "okay";
                        };
                };
        };

        __overrides__ {
                gpiopin = <&mfrc522_uio_pins>,"brcm,pins:0",
                        <&mfrc522_uio>,"interrupts:0";
        };
};
```

Compiled it by:

```sh
dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o mfrc522-uio-overlay.dt{bo,s}
```

and loaded:

```sh
sudo dtoverlay mfrc522-uio-overlay.dtbo
```

After module load:

```sh
sudo modprobe uio_pdrv_genirq of_id="mfrc522-uio,generic-uio"
```

the `/dev/uio0` should appear, but it **does not**. Kernel log shows nothing about this situation.

The workaround is to remove module:

```sh
sudo modprobe -r uio_pdrv_genirq
```

and load it  once again. Then the device appears in `/dev`.

There is no problem if I use kernel with built-in `uio_pdrv_genirq` driver and add to bootargs `uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id="mfrc522-uio,generic-uio"`. However, for some reasons I prefer to use distro's precompiled kernel.

**The question is**: why do I have to reload `uio_pdrv_genirq` module to get `/dev/uio0` device, and how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blank of_id in the uio_pdrv_genirq driver has the unintentional side-effect of causing userspace to view the module as a potential match for every platform device, thus the uio_pdrv_genirq module (if present) will always get automatically loaded at boot.  And since the module is already loaded, attempting to modprobe it with different settings has no effect (unless you unload the module first).

The solution is to create a `/etc/modprobe.d/uio_pdrv_genirq.conf` file containing

```
options uio_pdrv_genirq of_id=mfrc522-uio,generic-uio
```

This will make modprobe apply your setting automatically when the module gets loaded.